# preg_match_all - Match two options

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

preg_match confuses me so I apologise if this is a simple question or been asked before but I can't make sense of answer to know if its what I need.

I have a string that follows this format:
**Test 1#1.00 Test 2#2.00 Test 3#3.00**

I then use this pattern to seperate the values
`/(?P<first>([^**]*?))#(?P<second>\d{0,7}(?:\.\d{1,2}))/`

So end up with

**Array ( [0] => Test 1 [1] => Test 2 [2] => Test 3 )**

**Array ( [0] => 1.00 [1] => 2.00 [2] => 3.00 )**

Where I'm struggling is changing the pattern to find a decimal like it currently does or the word/letters FOC or TBC

So my string will be for example: **Test 1#1.00 Test 2#FOC Test 3#3.00**

and my arrays will be:

**Array ( [0] => Test 1 [1] => Test 2 [2] => Test 3 )**

**Array ( [0] => 1.00 [1] => FOC [2] => 3.00 )**

Currently, my pattern won't work with FOC and will just return the first in each array.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do `55.00` and `40.00` values come from? Are double `*` part of your input, or you use them to bold the sample string?

Comment: My apologies copied that from my actual outputs. I altered the question to be a bit simpler than my actual output. I have edited it

Comment: It's not a CSV string

Comment: Try [`(?P<first>[^#]*)#(?P<second>(?:\d{0,7}\.\d{1,2}|\w+))`](https://regex101.com/r/LBkRjj/3), and this [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/FEvP08)

Comment: Hi Wiktor, that seems to be working, could I trouble you in a little explanation, like what is the |\w and any reason as to what the format of decimal bits are different. I struggle with these codes and can never figure out what all the symbols do.

Comment: I added an answer with explanation and demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to add a `\w+` alternative before the regex engine tries to match a number:

```
(?P<first>[^#]*)#(?P<second>\d{0,7}\.\d{1,2}|\w+)
```

Or, to start matching keys with the first non-whitespace char ([demo](https://ideone.com/IHYWql)):

```
(?P<first>[^#\s][^#]*)#(?P<second>\d{0,7}\.\d{1,2}|\w+)
          ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LBkRjj/4/).

**Details**

- `(?P<first>[^#]*)` - Group "first" matching 0+ chars other than `#` (it is a negated character class here due to `^` being the first char after `[`)
- `#` - a `#` symbol
- `(?P<second>\d{0,7}\.\d{1,2}|\w+)` - Group "second" that matches

  - `\d{0,7}\.\d{1,2}` - 0 to 7 digits followed with `.` and then 1 or 2 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`)

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/wPmXZn):

```
$re = '/(?P<first>[^#]*)#(?P<second>(?:\d{0,7}\.\d{1,2}|\w+))/';
$str = 'Test 1#1.00 Test 2#2.00 Test 3#3.00
Test 1#1.00 Test 2#FOC Test 3#3.00';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches["first"]);
echo "\n";
print_r($matches["second"]);
```

Comment: Thanks mate thats a real help.